# MySql workbench Stored Procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

For my project, I am using MySQL workbench as  visual tool for my DB.
I'm using stored procedures in order to retrieve data. 
Until yesterday, everything worked well but today for some reason that’s what happened to me:

When using the stored procedure GUI, the software automatically creating a script where instead of taking the parameters that I inserted, it puts 0 in all the parameters.

For example (like in the pic) 
I inserted '1' as a parameter and the software did this script:

```
set @_ForumID = 0;
call forumgenerator.Get_SubForum_by_ForumID(@_ForumID);
select @_ForumID;
```

(instead of doing call forumgenerator.Get_SubForum_by_ForumID(1);
And ofcourse the answer was wrong.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMmhn.jpg)

If someone solved this problem and have a solution it will be great!

Comment: I think this is a known bug, not 100% sure, tho. But it's not a big deal. Simply change the set command to any value you want. You wouldn't start the run dialog every time you change the forum ID anyway, would you?

Comment: @MikeLischke this is one example with only one parameter, but most of my stored procedure have more parameters. anyway thanks for the advise, it's much easier way to handle with it. It's so weird because it worked before.

Comment: In case someone needs a guide to create store procedures on MySQL using Workbench here is a helpful tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WdievoP6570